# Variable and string substitution is not working for parameters

Tags: bash, azure, unix

The following bash script is to run an azure command:

```
#!/bin/bash
RG=$1
echo "az cosmosdb list-keys -g $1 -n db01"
echo "az cosmosdb list-keys -g $RG -n db01"
```

Then run the script with this command:

```
cosmokeys.sh main-Resource-Grp
```

The output is

```
az cosmosdb list-keys -g main-Resource-Grp -n db01
-n db01sdb list-keys -g main-Resource-Grp
```

I don't know Unix/Linux, beginner questions are:

1. How come `$1` and `$RG` will yield a different result?
2. How can I fix this so that I can still use `$RG` and yield the first result

Comment: There is most likely a CRLF behind `RG`. Can you have print your source using `cat -A` or `cat -vET`. You notice this as the output overwrites itself.

Comment: Thanks very much! You are correct and it solved my problem.